# Passing credentials though Jenkinsfile -> Docker-compose -> Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose

I need to shove credentials to a docker container via environment variables. This container is launched from a docker-compose file which is being maintained by Jenkins with CI/CD. I have the credentials stored in Jenkins as separate secret text entries under the domain of global. To the best of my knowledge, I can shim those credentials through via the `environment` block in my build stage using the `credentials` function. My attempt for the Jenkinsfile is shown below:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("build") {
            environment {
                DISCORD_TOKEN = credentials('DICEBOT_DISCORD_TOKEN')
                APPLICATION_ID = credentials('DICEBOT_APPLICATION_ID')
            }

            steps {
                sh 'docker-compose up --build --detach'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not much is printed for the error. All I get is this simple error: `ERROR: DICEBOT_APPLICATION_ID`. That is it. So is the scope of where I stored the secret text incorrect? I was reading that since the domain is global, anything should be able to access it. So maybe my idea for domain scoping is wrong? Is the location of `environment` in the Jenkinsfile wrong?
I am not sure. The error is very bland and does not really describe what it doesn't like about `DICEBOT_APPLICATION_ID`.

To make matters worse, fixing this issue doens't really even solve the main issue at hand: getting the docker container to hold these credentials. The issue that I am currently dealing with is just to scope the environment variables to running `docker-compose` and probably will not shim the environment variables into the container I need them in.

For the second part, getting docker-compose to pass on the credentials to the container, I think the snippet below might do the trick?

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  dicebot:
    environment:
      DISCORD_TOKEN: ${DISCORD_TOKEN}
      APPLICATION_ID: ${APPLICATION_ID}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The environment block is in the right location if you only intend on using those variables within that stage.  Your *docker-compose.yml* file looks fine but you aren't passing the environment variables as build arguments to the `docker-compose` command.  Please see my modifications below

```
 steps {
      sh "docker-compose build --build-arg DISCORD_TOKEN='$DISCORD_TOKEN' --build-arg APPLICATION_ID='$APPLICATION_ID' --detach --verbose"
      sh "docker-compose up -d"
 }
```

> I'm assuming the *docker-compose.yml* is in the same repository as your Jenkinsfile.  Be cognizant of the scope of your credentials.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion, which looks great for the second part (shimming the credentials to the container), however, I am currently getting blocked at the same error: `ERROR: DICEBOT_APPLICATION_ID`. Probably there is something wrong with the scoping of the credentials and Jenkins cannot find the credentials `DICEBOT_APPLICATION_ID`. Even though it is placed in the global domain?

Comment: I fixed the credentials issue. I apparently the build process did not have access to the credentials for the user account. So I created the credentials for "Jenkins" also under the global scope and that worked out just fine.

Comment: Secondly, the `--build-arg`  is apparently not a thing for `docker-compose up --build`, and is only available for `docker-compose build` directly. So I changed by Jenkins build steps to build using the traditional `build` instruction, then immediately call `docker-compose up -d` after the build was successful.

Comment: Finally, Jenkins built by using `${DISCORD_TOKEN}` spliced in, but it seems to want to use just simply `$DISCORD_TOKEN` as not to leak credentials in the logs. https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation
Thanks for the help! If you do not mind modifying the solution to accommodate those changes. I will give the answer the green tick as soon as the edits are put in.

Comment: I made some updates but if it's incomplete just self answer your question.  Also, I have ran into that same issue where you put credentials at a folder scope but then cannot access them.  I think that is an unresolved bug in Jenkins because unless a secret is in global scope I can never ever use it @jakebird451

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I want to solve it with the `.env` file so in that way I can pass more Environment to my Compose file

I came up with a solution that I was rendering my Secrets and using the `writeFile` directive to write it to the `.env` file but it's not the best solution

`writeFile file: ".env", text: "$mysecret"`

The challenge that I have is that there are other Environment variables as well to be appended to this file

Comment: Welcome. See [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for tips. You don't seem to be providing an improved answer to the question -which already has an accepted answer - but a half answer to your own question. I would advice to create your own question for that with more context on what you want. Piggy bagging on a different question is generally not helpful.